# Problems with CSS search results on web sites

Tags: php, css, .htaccess

bro, if I may ask
I have a CSS problem on the web, if I search the result of the web from Google it's a mess like CSS doesn't work ... but if you search directly on the web url, it can
please the solution, bro
**Thank you very much.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8wVH.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not post images. Put description/text directly in question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happen because the CSS is loaded over `HTTPS` protocol and you accessing the website with `HTTP` protocol,

You can fix this with forcing user to use `HTTPS`, on `.htaccess` write:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I'm really still learning, I still don't understand the script to be changed .. Can you help me? pls

This code .htaccess enter image description here

https://send.firefox.com/download/a923b65a95add0fa/#Gn7K-UMr7v0XJftDxf02Dg

I really thank you very much.